# Get linenumber of hanging script

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I recently "inherited" a complex PowerShell script that performs tasks in the background via task scheduler. Now we're seeing that the script hangs in some occasions, but until now I'm unable to identify the root cause.

Is there a way to pol or attach a debugger to an already running script so i can get the current line-number without rewriting large portions? In it's current state, the maintainability of the script is sub-par with 20k lines of code.

I tried checking WMI for properties, but found nothing useful. I did found a chronograph script that may be useful `https://powershellexplained.com/2017-02-05-Powershell-Chronometer-line-by-line-script-execution-times/` .

I also wrote a debugging wrapper, but the hang only happens in some occasions. I am unable to reproduce on demand.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `Start-Transcript`? that otta show you where things got to before hanging.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `Enter-PSHostProcess` ?

The `Enter-PSHostProcess` cmdlet connects to and enters into an interactive session with a local process. Instead of creating a new process to host PowerShell and run a remote session, the remote, interactive session is run in an existing process that is already running PowerShell. When you are interacting with a remote session on a specified process, you can enumerate running runspaces, and then select a runspace to debug by running either `Debug-Runspace` or `Enable-RunspaceDebug`

[Enter-PSHostProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pshostprocess?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: I tried this, but I'm somehow not able to enter the interactive session.